# empty variable in result

Tags: php, xml, opencart-3

i have colour options in opencart 3. black main +0 $10, option1 red +$2 ($12), option2 yellow +$3 ($13). sending prices to xml. i do not want black price in results.

```
$options = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($product['product_id']);
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $value) {
                $output .= '<outab>';
                $output .= '<Optional="' . $option['name'] . '" >' . $value['name'] . '</Optional>';
                $output .= '<Stock>' . $value['quantity']. '</stock>';
                $output .= '<Stocktab></Stoktab>';
                $output .= '<Stockmoney>' . ($value['price'] + $product['price']) * 1.10 . '</Stockmoney>';
```

selects the options, writes the prices in stockmoney tag, it writes blacks price.i want no result in black price.

```
$output .= '<Stockmoney>' . ($value['price'] + $product['price']) * 1.10 . '</Stockmoney>';
```

i tried (blacks price is main price, it has not $value['price'] so counts 0)

```
$blackprice = $value['price'] + $product['price'];
if ($blackprice = $product['price']) 
    { $blackprice ;} 
    else {empty($blackprice);}

$output .= '<Stockmoney>' . ($blackprice) * 1.10 . '</Stockmoney>';
```

Comment: you have messed up `=` vs `==` but im not sure that's the root issue here

Comment: tried == but red warning

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `{ $blackprice ;}  else {empty($blackprice);}`.  Normally you would have an assignment but your not doing anything with these lines of code.

Comment: You should also NOT build XML as strings as this can cause errors (for example `<Stocktab></Stoktab>`).  You can use SImpleXML to generate the data and then get it to create the XML string.

Answer (score 0):

more simple

`$a= $value['price'] + $product['price'];
if ($a > $product['price'])  { $a;} else { $a = null; }`

null outputs 0 which i do not want.

$value['price'] can be 0, if it is 0 than the result must be shown below. only xml tags without anything. 
`<Stockmoney></Stockmoney>`